# Why does "std::cout << char() << std::endl;" not even print a new line on Compiler Explorer?

Tags: c++, iostream, line-breaks, cout, compiler-explorer

This code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
    std::cout << char() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
}
```

[prints this](https://godbolt.org/z/Wc4vecajG):

```
---
---
```

Why isn't `std::endl` causing a new line to be between the other two?

Removing `char() <<` makes the output become what I expect:

```
---

---
```

Comment: If you try e.g. `std::cout << "||" << char() << "||" << std::endl;` what is printed then? Do you get all four bars?

Comment: By the way, what terminal are you using? Perhaps it has some special handling for the null character?

Comment: That's going to be an interpretation by your terminal. There is a null character in the output, which I think a terminal should just ignore as non-printable character, but I doubt that this is standardized anywhere. What terminal are you looking at?

Comment: It's reproducible on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/nfEcEPx6z

Comment: I've added the link to compiler explorer.

Comment: @jabaa GCC still produces the null character and newline character on stdout though. It gets skipped by the presentation on compiler explorer. That can easily happen, even unintentionally, if for example if something in the rendering code is handling each line individually, accidentally as a null-terminated string.

Comment: Strange. I've tried it with `sh`, `bash` and `zsh`. All print the newline. I can only reproduce it on Compiler Explorer. What's your actual environment?

Comment: It seems like this is not a question about C++, but about how Compiler Explorer prints the output. It's open source: https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer

Comment: Godbolt doctors its output a bit to hide some of its internals. For example: https://godbolt.org/z/TE84j7so9

Comment: Yeah, I'd file an issue on the Github repo, I don't think Stack Overflow is the place for bug reports.

Comment: It'd be nice if godbolt would output `␀` for a `char()`.  Next time I see Matt Godbolt, I'll mention it to him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code will cause the standard library to print a null character followed by a newline character to the stream.

How these characters are presented to you is a matter of the terminal or other UI you are using to view the stream's contents.

I would normally expect a terminal to skip the null character as non-printable and to interpret the newline as usual. However, I don't think there is any kind of standard or specification requiring this behavior.

In this concrete case I suspect a bug in how compiler explorer presents the output, probably in AnsiToHtml that is based on https://github.com/rburns/ansi-to-html and used to format output of the compiler containing ANSI escape codes. The library does some tokenization of the input, so a bug of this kind doesn't seem unlikely, but I don't know enough JavaScript/TypeScript to figure this out with a quick look.